# Mule CE JSON support erroring

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, mule

I have a  very basic REST service running under Mule 3.4 CE, using the default packages from the run-time.  Unlike several other services using the same techniques, this service throws unexplained errors.  I have attempted to add object-to-string, object-to-json and custom transformers.  But none of these additions have helped.  I have seen little in other posts here or in Mule Forums that have shed any light on this issue.  I have substituted the Java code into copies of other working services and get the same errors.

Any thoughts?

The JSON:

```
{
    "createDate" : "",
    "createdBy" : "RESTClient",
    "entry" : "RESTClient Work Log",
    "lastUpdate" : "",
    "lastUpdatedBy" : "",
    "requestTypeId" : 1003,
    "resourceId" : 5666,
    "workLogId" : 0
}
```

The POJO:

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class WorkLog {
    private String createDate;
    private String createdBy;
    private String entry;
    private String lastUpdate;
    private String lastUpdatedBy;
    private Integer requestTypeId;
    private Integer resourceId;
    private Integer workLogId;
    // snip
}
```

The REST service:

```
@Path("/worklogs")
public interface WorkLogWadlResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createWorkLog(@Context HttpHeaders hdr, @Payload final WorkLog log) throws Exception;
}
```

The Flow:

```html
<flow name="worklog-flow" doc:name="worklog-flow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" path="rest/worklogs" />
    <logger message="Work Log request, payload: #[message.payload]" level="DEBUG" doc:name="Logger" category="work_log_service" />
    <jersey:resources doc:name="Work Log REST Service">
        <component>
            <spring-object bean="restService" />
        </component>
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

The error:

```
ERROR 2015-01-23 15:53:40,906 [[worklog-mule-1.0.0].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]
    org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message: Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{worklog-flow.component.5062}.
    Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{worklog-flow.component.5062}.
    Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream
Code   : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. String index out of range: -1 (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)
  java.lang.String:1875 (null)
2. Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{worklog-flow.component.5062}.
    Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{worklog-flow.component.5062}.
    Message payload is of type: ContentLengthInputStream (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent:144
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEncodedPath(ContainerRequest.java:365)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getPath(ContainerRequest.java:358)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Can you try removing the `@Payload` annotation on `log`? I don't think Jersey needs it.

Comment: If no better, please repost the stacktrace when running Mule with `-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true`. And also show how you build the `Response` instance in `restService`.

Comment: David, thank you for taking the time to respond.  I agree that @Payload is superfluous.  I added it in an attempt to see it's benefit, only after finding no success elsewhere.  I will try repeating the calls with the Mule exceptions flag enabled.  I build these Response objects in several different ways, depending on the service, but the calls are never progressing far enough in this case to shed more light in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was purely a Jersey Path error that was not clearly logged.  Operator error....

BTW - the Mule verbose logging added no detail in this case.